# How to select an element based on the property of an object inside a data attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, custom-data-attribute

If my markup looks like this:

```
<div data-test="{ "value" : "bar", "_id" : 1234, "name" : "john", "age" : 25 }">...</div>
<div data-test="{ "value" : "foo", "_id" : 1235, "name" : "paul", "age" : 26 }">...</div>
<div data-test="{ "value" : "drummer", "_id" : 1236, "name" : "ringo", "age" : 22 }">...</div>
```

How would I select a particular element using JQuery if I only had the key 'bar' or 'foo'?

I could pull out the whole object for each row and iterate through it looking for a match but I'd rather not if there is a more efficient method.

How can I cleanly select based on the property of an object?

Comment: jQuery uses xpath for selecting object.
Xpath has no support for embedded json structures.

Comment: But this: `$('#myDiv').data('value')` returns `bar` or `foo` so JQuery is able to operate on the object, no?

Comment: "returns bar or foo" ?? Not with this markup and code...

Comment: Can you use JSON syntax in your markup? Then you could use `JSON.parse()` and match the `value` element more cleanly. The difference is that you need to use double quotes rather than single quotes around the strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$("div").filter(function() {
    return $(this).data("test").value == "bar";
})
```

`jQuery.data()` automatically parses a data value that's in JSON format into the corresponding object.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/qEFSe/1/)

Comment: `.filter()` is a more accurate solution as it will only return exact matches.

Comment: You need to change your outer quotes to single quotes or escape the inner double quotes.

Comment: You'd think so but actually Chrome renders the html like this (even when the template code is using single quotes) and, despite it looking wrong, I am able to successfully access the object using JQuery's `.data()` method. I admit, it's odd, but it's working.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('div[data-test$=": bar }"]')
$('div[data-test$=": foo }"]')
```

More details [here](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

**UPDATE:**
If attributes are not ending with bar/foo then you could try `contains selector`

```
$('div[data-test*="'value' : 'bar'"]')
$('div[data-test*="'value': 'foo'"]')
```

More details [here](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

Or you could also use [starts selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) if it starts with value

Comment: I should have been clearer, the actual object is much more complicated and does not end with the value property. I'll update the question with a more accurate example.

Comment: If this solution works for you, then you are not interested in properties, but rather in attributes. That selector won't work for data properties set by, for example, `.data("stuff", "things")`.