# select attribute of an element inside data-content of a popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-popover

I was using Bootstrap 4 popover and suddenly got stuck with this issue. The problem is I can not select the attribute inside data-content of a popover. Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
 <a data-toggle='popover' data-placement='left' tabindex='0' data-trigger='focus' data-html='true' data-content="<div class='pop-div'><a href='#' class='text-center edit_web_ac' data-id='{$row['id']}' data-table='web_accounts'>Edit</a><br><a href='#' class='text-center del_web_ac'>Delete</a></div>">Options</a>
```

If you look closely, **data-content** attribute has two `<a>` tag inside it. I am using JQuery to select the attribute (**data-id**) of this inner `<a>` tag. I've tried `$(this).attr('data-id');` which returns `undefined`. So, my question is, how to get the attribute of this `<a>` [To be clear, the `<a>` which has a class `.edit_web_ac`].

I've tried these solutions, But none of these fully match with my situation.

[How to select Element Id inside attribute tag with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36092652/how-to-select-element-id-inside-attribute-tag-with-jquery)

[How to select an element based on the property of an object inside a data attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12950554/how-to-select-an-element-based-on-the-property-of-an-object-inside-a-data-attrib)

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

```html
<html>
<head>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

 <a data-toggle='popover' data-placement='left' tabindex='0' data-trigger='focus' data-html='true' data-content="<div class='pop-div'><a href='#' class='text-center edit_web_ac' data-id='{$row['id']}' data-table='web_accounts'>Edit</a><br><a href='#' class='text-center del_web_ac'>Delete</a></div>">Options</a>


<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover({
        delay: 100
    });

   $('body').on('click', '.edit_web_ac', function (e) { 
     e.preventDefault();
     var content = $(this).attr('data-id');
     alert(content); //returns 'undefined'
   })

  })
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the data-content with seperate div and call the id through jquery content

```
<a href = '#' data-toggle='popover' data-placement='left' tabindex='0' data-trigger='focus'>Options</a>
```

Remove data-content from your anchor tag and place it as separate div

```
<div class='pop-div' style = 'display:none;'><a href='#' class='text-center edit_web_ac' data-id='{$row['id']}' data-table='web_accounts'>Edit</a><br><a href='#' class='text-center del_web_ac'>Delete</a></div>
```

and in the jquery add

```
$(function () {
            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
              toggle: 'popover',
              placement: 'right',
              title: 'Options',
              html: true,
              content: function () {
                  return $('.pop-div').html();
              },
            });
    });
```

Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to put the HTML content in a separate div with an ID:

```
<a data-toggle='popover' data-placement='left' tabindex='0' data-trigger='focus' data-html='true' data-content="YOURID">Options</a>

<div id="YOURID">
   <div class='pop-div'>
       <a href='#' class='text-center edit_web_ac' data-id='{$row['id']}' data-table='web_accounts'>Edit</a><br><a href='#' class='text-center del_web_ac'>Delete</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

In JavaScript / jQuery something like this:

```
var content = $('#YOURID .edit_web_ac').data('id);
```

Comment: Thank you @TYPO3 Freelancer, but this doesn't solve my problem properly. This is a popover, so if I put the `HTML` of `data-content` outside the `popover` it just doesn't show up on click. You see, I have two `<a>` inside `data-content`, and both of them have different functions upon clicking on them.